# UIScrollView Quick Taps Not Being Fired *Bug*

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm seeing an issue with UITableViews and UIScrollViews. For a UITableViewCell to be selected you have to give it a fairly long tap for it to register. A quick tap on the screen won't do the job. Setting delayContentTouches to NO isn't the answer either because it highlighted cells "too fast" as compared to how it should work properly.

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: Post some of your code. I use uitableview and scrollviews in my current app for ios 6 and they never require a long press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using some weird 3rd-party code that was adding categories to UITouch.... figures.